# Defining a Threshold level for the Mahalanobis distance in R

Tags: r

I would like to know if there is any function in R that calculates the threshold level for the Mahalanobis distance such that the probability mass of the ellipsoid is set equal to a certain α, say 0.99.

Thanks,

Juan.

Comment: for multivariate normal distribution? if yes, I think what you need is a chi-square distribution.

Comment: Do you mean that if for example I have 3 varialbes, assuming multivariate normal distribution I have to calculate 99% of a chi-square with 3 df and that will give me the Maha threshold?

Comment: should be the square root of 99 percentile of chi square with df 3.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics: it should be migrated to [stats.se].